# posts_per_page is not working on my end

Tags: posts

I have these lines of codes, for some reason, `posts_per_page` is not working.

```
<?php
        $posts_list = get_posts(
            array(
                'posts_per_page'    => 6,
                'post_type'         => 'post',
                'post_status'       => 'publish',
                'paged'             => $i_paged
            )
        );

        $the_query = new WP_Query( $posts_list );

        // The Loop
        if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

                global $post;

                $the_query->the_post();

                $post_id = get_the_id();

                // Get fields
                $image      = get_the_post_thumbnail();
                $title      = get_the_title();
                $subtitle   = get_the_date();
                $content    = get_the_excerpt();
                $link       = get_permalink();

                $args['cards'][] = array(
                    'image'         => $image,
                    'title'         => $title,
                    'subtitle'      => $subtitle,
                    'content'       => $content,
                    'link'          => $link,
                );

                ?>

            <?php }

        } else {
            // no posts found
        }

        echo '<div class="posts-grid">';
                get_template_part( '/blocks/testimonial/testimonial-template', null, $args );
        echo '</div>';

        /* Restore original Post Data */
        wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>
```

Comment: Well.. Is that `get_posts` a typo? You should do `$posts_list = array( ... your args ... );` and not `$posts_list = get_posts( ... );` .. Also, I don't see where `$i_paged` is defined, and I would move the `global $post;` to outside the `while`..

Comment: Ahh thanks @SallyCJ, the `get_posts` was the culprit. I removed it and it worked. Thank you!!

Comment: Glad I could help and I can post an answer if you want me to. Otherwise, you can write your own and accept it later. 

Comment: You can post your answer! I'd appreciate that. :) @SallyCJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not working because the `$posts_list` variable is assigned the return value of [`get_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/) (i.e. `$posts_list = get_posts( ... )`), hence `$posts_list` is not actually an array of arguments, but instead, it's either an array of [posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_post/) or an empty array.

So to fix the problem, define the `$posts_list` like so:

```php
$posts_list = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'paged'          => $i_paged
);
```

Comment: PS: You should rename the variable, e.g. to `$posts_args` and then use `new WP_Query( $posts_args )`. :)

Comment: Thank you so much!